# 'IpICSHlpStopSharing' : '0x80070490' in event log

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, windows-error-reporting

Suddenly I begin to see a lot of errors in my event log (Windows 10 Pro Build 19041):

*'IpICSHlpStopSharing' : '0x80070490'.*

*Source: Host-Network service.*

I am working with Hyper-V (and Docker) and everything seems to work fine so far, but I am wondering where this error comes from and how I can avoid it. I have done some research and found that enabling windows sandbox environment may solve the error, however it did not. There are also some similar errors occuring like:

*'IpICSHlpStopDnsServer' : '0x80070490'*

*'IpICSHlpStopDnsServer' : '0x80070490'*

Does anyone know whats the issue here?
XML of the error:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Host-Network-Service" Guid="{0c885e0d-6eb6-476c-a048-2457eed3a5c1}" /> 
  <EventID>1030</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-07-08T08:54:22.1565118Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>221</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="2476" ThreadID="2552" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Host-Network-Service-Admin</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-PTT2TUS</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="HResult">0x80070490</Data> 
  <Data Name="API">3</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seeing the same. Also getting errors trying to copy files across the network ...‍♀️

Comment: I have the same error on Windows 11 (I also just began to use Docker).